# MariaDB Select get value from inner select

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, mariadb

i have a select which has two inner selects previously i needed values only from outer select, but now i need to get value also from inner select:

```
SELECT
  a.Id,
  a.Position,
  b.CompanyId
FROM Positions a
WHERE Employee IN (
  SELECT IdEMEmployee
  FROM Employees b
  WHERE CompanyId IN (
    SELECT CompanyId
    FROM Parameters c
    WHERE CompanyParameter = 'Test Company')) AND
      (ValidUntil > '2018-01-01' OR ValidUntil IS NULL) AND
      (ValidFrom < '2017-01-01' OR ValidFrom IS NULL)
ORDER BY a.Position, a.Id DESC;
```

The problem that is `b.CompanyId` is not reachable is it possible to do it without joins ?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without joins? You can use a subquery... but you should really use a join

Comment: I agree with Milney: by using joins, the database engine will evaluate the best path to execute the query. Use select DISTINCT to ignore double lines.